# Can't read yaml's complex object using @ConfigurationProperties. Integer cannot be cast to String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, yaml, lombok

I'm trying to read this yml file

```
dist-price:
  1234:
    foo: 4567
    bar: false
```

and put into this class. (I'm using Lombok and Spring Boot v1.5.4.RELEASE)

```
@Repository
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WebConfigProperty {
    @NonNull
    private TreeMap<Integer, Bound> distPrice;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bound {
    @NonNull
    private Integer foo;

    @NonNull
    private Boolean bar;
}
```

But I got this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.isBlanked(RelaxedDataBinder.java:328)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.initializePath(RelaxedDataBinder.java:283)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.normalizePath(RelaxedDataBinder.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperty(RelaxedDataBinder.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:272)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:329)
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

If I change `TreeMap<Integer, Bound>` to `TreeMap<String, Bound>` it works fine. But I really need to use `Integer`. It seems like `TreeMap`'s key (in this case: `1234`) is being cast to `String`. I don't know why.

It was fine when `TreeMap<Integer, Bound>` was `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>`, and yml was like this.

```
dist-price:
  1234: 4567
```

**EDIT:** I tried Spring Boot `v1.5.9.RELEASE`, but no luck.

Comment: I think this is a bug.

Comment: @aristotll I'm starting to think so too. I'm using a workaround for now. I'm using Spring Boot v1.5.4.RELEASE.

Comment: @Stephane Is using a number as a key is forbidden? See also Johnny Lim's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample project from the question: https://github.com/izeye/so-48071057

and confirmed the exception is thrown from this line: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedDataBinder.java#L328

As you can see, `key` is typed as `String` and it's the root cause of the exception. I'm not sure this is legit usage or not as I never thought about `Integer` key for it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but [if I read this doc correctly](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#key//), `The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique. YAML places no further restrictions on the nodes.` So Integer as a key is legit. I guess It's a bug. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @user2652379 The "legit" meant for configuration properties, not for YAML. I think Stephane could give you the answer for whether it's legit or not.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `@ConfigurationProperties` but the way YAML handle keys. Keys in YAML are `String` by default so if you really want to use integer there you have to force it somehow.

There are several documented ways to do this, quoting is supposed to work but didn't work for me ('1234' gave me back 234!). Forcing an integer using `!!int` works

```
dist-price:
  !!int 1234:
    foo: 4567
    bar: false
```