# ConfigurationProperties binding a property name with a number in from a yaml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I'm new to Spring-Boot and have a problem binding a property value in the application.yml file to class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperies`.

In the application.yml:

```
aaa:
  what-1word-is: true
```

In the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aaa")
public class Test
{
    private boolean what1WordIs;
}
```

I tried with different names for the property,
but none of them works;
`what1WordIs` is always `false`.
Names I tried, 
`what-1-word-is`,
`what-1word-is`,
`what1-word-is`,
`what-1Word-is`.
Only `what1-word-is` works(set `what1WordIs` in configuration class to `true`)

Is Spring able to bind a property with a number in its name?

Comment: As alluded to in the @Alexander Polozov answer, the actual property name (because you are using YAML configuration) is `aaa.what-1-word-is`.  The prefix matters.

Comment: Thx for the suggestions. I forgot to add `prefix = "aaa"` in the question, but I do have it in the code

Answer (score 4):

It should work.
I have tried and it works for me. Even for 'what-1-word-is'.

application.yml

```
aaa:
  what-1-word-is: true
```

Config.class

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aaa")
@Data
public class Config {
  private boolean what1WordIs;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
      System.out.println("CONFIG :: "+this);
  }
}
```

As result we can see :

```
CONFIG :: Config(what1WordIs=true)
```

I think you faced this issue because you used @Configuration annotation instead of @Component.

BTW: Spring allows us to use different property names in config file. I've tried all options you've mentioned and it works. (More: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding )

BTW2: If you want take a look which properties Spring expects you can add into dependency this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

It will generate `spring-configuration-metadata.json` in `/target/classes/META-INF` directory where all properties are described.
Example:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "aaa",
      "type": "com.supra89kren.test_spring.configurtion.Config",
      "sourceType": "com.supra89kren.test_spring.configurtion.Config"
    }
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "aaa.what1-word-is",
      "type": "java.lang.Boolean",
      "sourceType": "com.supra89kren.test_spring.configurtion.Config",
      "defaultValue": false
    }
  ],
  "hints": []
}
```

Moreover, an IDE will be able to autocomplete for you :)

BTW3: Please check, that you use @Data from Lombok library.

I hope it's still actual :)

Comment: That reference to `spring-configuration-metadata.json` (and how to get it :-p) was a lifesaver! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to propose something different than was is being asked. I might suggest not allowing numbers in the properties file.

You might try to set your property name to something like the following if possible:

`aaa:
    what-single-word-is`

or maybe something a little shorter:

`aaa:
    single-word`

[Can't read yaml's complex object using @ConfigurationProperties. Integer cannot be cast to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071057/cant-read-yamls-complex-object-using-configurationproperties-integer-cannot)

Comment: Thx for the suggestion! I replaced number with other characters, it works anyway. May need to dig more how it actually works